# What to do with a community URL style like Last.FM or Wikipedia?

Tags: php, mysql, url, url-rewriting, url-style

I'm trying to understand how I should work with characters in `URLs`, this because I'm building a site where the user can store content and go to the content's page by digiting it's name in the `URL`.

so, something like `Wikipedia` or `Last.FM` website.

I see in the site, user can write something like
`http://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trentemøller` and the page of the artist can reached.

after the page is loaded, if I copy the URL i see written as:
`http://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trentemøller` but if I paste it into a text editor, it will be pasted as
`http://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trentem%C3%B8ller`

so the char `ø` is pasted as `%C3%B8`

of course the same is for URLs like this (the page of the artist Takeshi Kobayashi)

`http://www.last.fm/music/小林武史`
`http://www.last.fm/music/%E5%B0%8F%E6%9E%97%E6%AD%A6%E5%8F%B2`

If I digit the first or the second, the page works in any case, why?

I think I should do something with the `.htacces` and `mod_rewrite` but I'm not sure, are the special chars automatically converted to the url special chars?

and then, how can I do to let PHP do the right query with the content name?

if I have a table like

```
table_users
- username
- age
- height
- weight
- sex
- email
- country
```

I'm able with `mod_rewrite` to write an address like `http://mysite.com/user/bob` to get the `username` bob from the `table_users` but what about `http://mysite.com/user/小林武史`?

here I show a simple example of what I think to do:

```
#.htaccess
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(user/)([a-zA-Z0-9_+-]+)([/]?)$ user.php?username=$2

<?php
// this is the page user.php
// this is the way I use to get the url value
print $_REQUEST["username"];
?>
```

this works, but it's limited to [a-zA-Z0-9_+-], how to be more compatible with all chars like the others without loss too much security?

Did someone know some way to avoid troubles?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most browsers `urlencode()` `小林武史` to `%E5%B0%8F%E6%9E%97%E6%AD%A6%E5%8F%B2`.

Reguarding your `.htaccess` `mod_rewrite` rules, have you considered using something like:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(user/)(.+?)[/]?$ user.php?username=$2
```

Answer (score 5):

Try urlencode and urldecode

Edit :

Here is Visualy the Description of url encoding and decoding

http://blog.neraliu.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/10/url-encoding.png

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand every URL with not ASCII characters is mapped to unique ASCII based url. This is actually a feature on the client side. Please look at: http://kmeleon.sourceforge.net/bugs/viewbug.php?bugid=631 to see examples and link to RFCs coverting this one.